# Why the Java Compiler does not identify the generic parameter type and indirectly asking to cast?

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a generic method that handles requests type of a generic interface and returns a generic response as well.

Aforementioned are my interfaces, the method, and the Pojos.

```
public interface Request {
}

public interface Response {
}

public class MyRequest implements Request{
   //SomeFields
}

public class MyResponse implements Response{
   //SomeFields
}
```

Now, I was writing a request handler, where there is a method

```
public <T extends Response, S extends Request> T handle(S request) {

        String decoratedMsg = requestDecorator.writeAsJsonifiedString(request);
        sqsAccessor.pushMessage(decoratedMsg,"SomeURL");
        MyRequest myRequest = (MyRequest) request;
        return (T) buildResponse(MyRequest);
    }

private MyResponse buildResponse(MyRequest request) {
   return new MyResponse();
}
```

This issue with the above code is that I have to cast my response while calling the private method buildResponse, but I am just wondering that while defining T I have specified that T extends Response and my private method returns MyResponse which implements Response, so why does the casting is required?

Comment: `T` is not necessarily `MyResponse`.

Comment: Try changing return type of `buildResponse` to `Response`.

Comment: If `S` is some subtype of `Request` but other than `MyRequest`, or `T` a subtype of `Response` but other than `MyResponse`, you will get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildResponse` takes as a parameter a `MyRequest` and returns a `MyResponse`.

However, what you pass to `handle` can be *any* (any subclass) `Request` and what is returned can be *any* `Response`

Even after you change `buildResponse` as

```
private Response buildResponse(Request request) {
   return new MyResponse();
}
```

the compiler forces you<sup>1</sup> to cast the response as `return (T) buildResponse(request);`

If your method is going to return a subclass of `Response` there is no need to have the type parameter `T`. Instead, you can mark the return type as `Response`.

```
public <S extends Request> Response handle(S request)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This results in unchecked cast, making your code non-type safe.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `T` extends `Response`, which means `T` can be any subclass of response not just `MyResponse`. Here the method `buildResponse` returns `MyResponse` that is not necessary the same type as the current `T` generic.

For instance if you call

```
MyOtherResponse myOtherResponse = this.<MyOtherResponse, MyRequest>handle(request);
```

where:

```
public static class MyOtherResponse implements Request {
    //SomeFields
}
```

You would be returning a `MyRequest` instead of a `MyOtherResponse` which will throw a `ClassCastException`.

If your are always going to return a `MyResponse` class you should change the `handle` method to:

```
public <S extends Request> MyResponse handle(S request)
```

By the other hand if you can return different subclasses of `Response`then you cannot use that `buildResponse` method, instead you could use generics in this method too (maybe receiving a `Class<T>`), and constructing the necessary instance.